# Rails - Conditions Include Multiple Items In An Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, conditional-statements

```
p = Person.find_by_id(1, :include => :bags, :conditions => ['bag.id in (?), [3,4])
```

I would like to know how I could make sure this query will only be valid if both 'items.id' '3' & '4' are present rather than '3' or/and '4'.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In Plain SGL : SELECT * FROM persons p INNER JOIN bags_persons b1 ON b1.person_id = p.id INNER JOIN bags_persons b2 ON b2.person_id = p.id 
WHERE b1.bag_id = 3 AND b2.bag_id = 4 The point is you need to join 2 times in order to search for both bags at the same time. Maybe there is a neater way to write it in rails, but with :joins and :conditions you'll be able to translate this query into the find syntax.

Comment: Btw, :include is mainly used to prefetch the bags in the resulting person Object, so if you don't access the bags of it after this request :joins will be enough.

Comment: What's the setup? person has_many :bags and bag belongs_to person?

Comment: @jacob I am trying to run a single query that will return the person only if they have the associated bags.  @marko The setup is "person has_many :persons_bags, has_many :bags, :through => :peoples_bags", "peoples_bag belongs_to :person, belongs_to :bag", and "bags has_many :peoples_bag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually construct your 2 inner joins to the bags_persons table:

```
Person.find_by_id(1, :joins => "INNER JOIN bags_persons bp1 ON bp1.person_id=persons.id INNER JOIN bags_persons bp2 ON bp2.person_id=persons.id", :conditions => "bp1.bag_id=3 AND bp2.bag_id=4")
```

Hope this helps